# Jquery Timeago add AM/PM in title

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, timeago

Im using [Timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/)  plugin to replace date and time with *2 minute ago* . After i implement 
with my php code :

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timeago/0.9.3/jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
  });
</script>

<abbr class="timeago ticket_date" title="<?= date("Y-m-d  h:i:s A", strtotime($ticket_row_message['date_added'])); ?>"><?= date("Y-m-d  h:i:s", strtotime($ticket_row_message['date_added'])); ?></abbr>
```

The problem that i found is when im hover my mouse to `abbr` the title only show `2013-03-14 11:06:44` without AM PM. So how to add AM PM, any trick to do this ?

Comment: its ok .. problem fix .. just add "Y-m-d  h:i:s A" for both ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a PHP issue.
Your first one is using:

```
<?= date("Y-m-d  h:i:s A", strtotime($ticket_row_message['date_added'])); ?>
```

Your second one is using:

```
<?= date("Y-m-d  h:i:s", strtotime($ticket_row_message['date_added'])); ?>
```

Just add the "A" to the second one too.